# Vuetify v-autocomplete reactivity problem

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

It seems that I've run into a pretty basic issue.

I am using the Vuetify component library and in a form the `v-autocomplete` component.
Also I am using vuex.

Say I have a vuex product module. The product has a key `retailer`. So something like this:

```
product: {
  name: "My Product",
  price: 100,
  serialNumber: "1234",
  retailer: {
    name: "My Retailer",
    ...
  }
}
```

The retailer is its own entity in the API.
In the product form I want to search the API for available retailers using the `v-autocomplete` component.

To do this I am mapping the `product`-state into my `ProductForm`-component (`computed: {...mapstate("products", ["product"])}`) and configure `v-autocomplete` as follows:

```
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="product.retailer"
        :items="retailerItems"
        :search-input.sync="retailerSearch"
        hide-no-data
        hide-selected
        item-text="name"
        item-value="id"
        label="Retailer"
        placeholder="Search"
        return-object
      ></v-autocomplete>
```

When I then `POST` my product, it gets correctly sent to the API.
After the `POST` is finished, I immediately do a `GET` on the same ressource (because the API response does not send nested data) and my new product is put correctly into the state.

Here is the problem: After the `POST` the `v-autocomplete` field is empty. The state it is bound to contains the new data in the same format as before.

Is doing `mapState()` the wrong thing? Should I put the new value in an action and commit it to the state?
Or is the problem that `retailer` is nested data?
I don't have the problem with text-fields.
Or is this a reactivity issue of the `v-autocomplete` component?

I know it sounds convoluted but I tried to paint a complete picture and perhaps someone stumbled on that issue before.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Because the repopulation of the state and that the bound value did not get typed in, no actual search against the API was triggered and so the component had no data to choose from. Turning on `cache-items` gave the component the previously loaded values to choose from and so the current value in the store can get displayed.